# DocType not visible under Module view

Tags: python, doctype, erpnext, frappe

I have created two DocTypes inside the education module. I've unchecked the "custom" checkbox to build the `js` and `py` files. However, the two DocTypes have not listed inside the education module.

If I check the custom they return to list under setup so how I can list him inside the education module while the custom is unchecked?

another question: I have created a custom script for one of these DocTypes, will I lose the script after unchecked custom !!!

`Note: I can find them in the global search`

Answer (score 0):

For `version-12` you'll have to override the `get_data` under `education` of the `config` module. The file for that is [here](https://github.com/frappe/erpnext/blob/version-12/erpnext/config/education.py)

If you are on the `develop` branch, as a consequence of the desk refactor you might have to update an additional file, specifically [education.json](https://github.com/frappe/erpnext/blob/develop/erpnext/education/desk_page/education/education.json) file with your newly created modules.

Answer (score -1):

Try Bench Migrate First for Standard DocType

Comment: OP has clearly stated that this is regarding custom DocTypes